# How to delete a file from the GRUB terminal?

Tags: grub2, 15.04

I created a `.conf` file when trying to fix a brightness issue. I followed these instructions: http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

so how can I delete `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`?

`rm` and `purge` doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show the exact command you tried; ii) the exact error message you received ("doesn't work" isn't very informative)iii) explain why you need to do it from the GRUB terminal. Can't you boot into your operating system?

Comment: By GRUB terminal - do you mean the Ubuntu rescue root shell or the GRUB rescue console?

Comment: The commands were not recognized, and no I cannot boot. I have a live key, can I boot a live session and delete it from there?

Comment: @ByteCommander GRUB rescue console

Comment: Sure you can access the file system from a live system. That will be the easiest way if you can't even get to the recovery root shell.

Comment: ok, will it be as simple as `sudo rm file.conf` or will it be in another partition?

Comment: @dragonsarefake  [Follow the Update Recovery part](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) on that link;  It's strange you got to GRUB recovery with simply messing around with a file.  I suggest after you done mounting all folders as shown in the link , remove that file and also run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub` which should fix grub

Comment: I think it's because (Brace for stupidity) what that file does is force use the intel nouveau drive to control brightness. The part where I look like an idiot is I had previously purged that drive :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only affects your computer's ability to boot from the HDD. You can still boot into a live system from usb and delete it in the live session.

Comment: That's what I did, it got buried in the comments though. should I delete the question? I delete one yesterday because I also found the answer and I don't know if this qualifies as too recent. Or should I just mark your answer as accepted for those who have the same problem?

Comment: @dragonsarefake I'm unsure whether it's appropriate to accept this as an answer, at least to what's being asked **in the title**. Future visitors (like myself, right now) might benefit from an answer explaining how to actually delete files **from the grub console**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the graphical desktop is not starting up.

1. Switch to a different console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>...
2. From this text-based login prompt you'll be able to **login** and use the command line.
3. `$ sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
4. `$ shutdown -r now`